# SQL - Trigger for refresh datagrid when placing data in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, datagridview

I'm having some difficulties with the triggers. I have a datagrid column `ValorIva` in table `regsitrab_db`, from the "GTA_db" when I insert an `IVA` value, I need to do a refresh to write `ValorIva` in the datagrid. How can I do it?

I have tried this:

```
create trigger Atualizar_Iva
on RegisTrab_db
After insert
as
Begin
    Declare @valor decimal(3, 2)

    Select @Valor = Valor

    Update ValorIva 
    set ValorIva = @Valor * 1,23
end
go
```

The goal is: I have a number in column `IVA` and I need to trigger that number to multiply by 1.23. Something like this ... 50 * 1.23 and show de data in `ValorIva`

Valor=50
valoriva=61,5 (50*1.23)

Thanks

Comment: Hello, what database do you use? Oracle, MySQL or something else?

Comment: i´m using SQL Server

Comment: You don't need trigger for that, check for "Computed columns", for example [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-ver15](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are using decimal comma instead of decimal point:

```
set ValorIva = @Valor * 1,23
```

should be:

```
set ValorIva = @Valor * 1.23
```

But, I would personally store the input value in a separate column (i.e. Iva) and use another `Computed` column (IvaCalc) to calculate whatever required (e.g. Iva*1.23).

Answer (score 0):

create trigger AtualizarIva_trg
on RegisTrab_db

after insert
as
Begin
Declare
@Valor decimal(3,2)

Select @Valor=Valor FROM inserted

update  RegisTrabdb 
SET ValorIva = @Valor * 1.23

end

go

This code works( dont give a error), but the db stays the same ... what i´m doing wrong